threejs clipping planes on pointcloud / gaussian splatting
I need to clip data from a gaussian splatting. From what I understand, it follows a similar structure as a pointcloud. So any workflow that can help to make the clipping planes work on pointclouds might me a good starting point.
This is my proof of concept using 1 clipping plane. Anything located in the right must be clipped however, the gaussian is not reacting to render.clippingPlanes setup:

render.clippingPlanes = [
  plane1,
];

Prevu3d has a good examples of the outcome I wish to achieve:
This is the bounding box:

and here is an example with the isolation feature enabled:

